# Load content into div only on click with additional

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, onclick

Ok Im trying to do a few different things but they are all pretty simple. I can only find answers that somewhat give a piece of what Im trying to do and when I mix and match different answers they don't work well together. I figured it would be better to ask specifically.

[image]

The hidden divs on the bottom are filled with images so I only want them to load when a link is clicked and not when the page is loaded. Each hidden div will have three divs of its own that target the three top divs so when you click the link for that hidden div all three of the divs in that hidden div load into the three top divs. I'm pretty sure I know how to make one link trigger different events so you don't have to help me there unless you know a simpler way to do this. Here are the main things I need help with:

- loading div content only on click and not page load
- targeting a div to load other div content into
- when link is clicked to open a new hidden div,  the other hidden div that was showing goes away
- and because this is a tech website it would be nice to have some kind of tech-y transition when switching between/loading new divs. If nothing else a fade would work but you don't have to help me with this part, just if you happen to know a code or webpage with different transition effects for loading content that would be nice.

I don't really have any pre written code yet that will conflict with whatever you suggest so you can suggest anything. You don't have to write everything out, I can catch on with an example. Maybe.

Thank you I know there are separate individual answers but again I have had trouble trying to get them to work together or they will do part of what I need but not the other. I thought if I just asked instead someone could whip up a code for me in like 5 minutes. Thanks.

edit: Ill add code but I don't think it'll help much.

```
<div id="menu"> <a> -Cyber glasses Link- that opens cyberglasses div and loads it into presentation div </a></div>

<div id="presentation">
<div id="div-pic-1">Empty space to load stuff into</div>
<div id="center-content">Empty space to load stuff into</div>
<div id="div-pic-2">Empty space to load stuff into</div>
</div>


<div id="cyberglasses">(this div does not appear on pageload and only loads on click of the menu link named "Cyber glasses Link" at top of page)

<div id="cg1"> picture 1 of cyber glasses to load into id div-pic-1 </div>
<div id="cgcontent"> description of cyber glasses to load into id center-content</div>
<div id="cg2"> picture 2 of cyber glasses to load into id div-pic-2<div>

</div>
```

The menu link at the top named -Cyber glasses Link- loads div cg1 into div-pic-1

and div cgcontent into center-content

and div cg2 into div-pic-2

all at the same time. But the only div that loads on page load is the presentation div and menu div not the cyberglasses div. Cyberglasses div only loads on click of the cyber glasses link.

Comment: 3 divs, 3 top divs, hidden divs, .... I'm totally lost in your question. Plase, make your pictures cristal clear and paste some code. Shorten and simplify maximally your question, make it understandable. (here we like simple and concise questions) Welcome to SO

Comment: A little bit of code??? show your advance in code

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="welcome.html" rel="#content">Welcome</a>
            <a href="frog.html" rel="#image">Frog</a>
            <a href="lamma.html" rel="#image">Lamma</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="image"></div>
        <script>
          $(function(){
            $('#navigation').on('click','a',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $($(this).attr('rel')).load($(this).attr('href'));
            });
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Demo: https://oteck.co.uk/sample/load.html